# China spy balloon story. International implications of the use of foreign airspace

Tags: china, espionage

This is a follow up to [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78171/what-would-be-the-advantages-of-balloon-over-other-spying-tech-for-china).

If I understood correctly the USA are not complaining for a single episode, but [they claim](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-64614098) that China set up a worldwide surveillance system using balloons. The difference from a system based on satellites is that the balloons have to enter the airspace of foreign countries. AFAIK above the height of 100 Km there is no reserved airspace. Therefore for satellites which are way above the threshold there is no violation of the airspace, while balloons are way below that threshold.

Until now countries ignored balloons entering their airspace because they considered them innocuous meteorological balloons. But if other countries join the US and classify them as spy/surveillance balloons will they start complaining about the invasion of their airspace. Could there be accusations of violating the international law regarding the airspace?

Balloons are very difficult to control, I guess that also many foreign weather balloons entered the Chinese airspace, would the Chinese begin to complain about them? Is there a way to define the difference between the two?

Comment: No balloon has been invented that can reach 100 km altitude.

Comment: Max altitude for balloons is round-about 135,000 feet, round about 41 km.  Balloons without some other tech (rockets etc.) are unlikely to go much higher than that. The recent balloons in the news have been round-about 100,000 feet, a little higher or lower at times.

Comment: *The difference from a system based on satellites is that the balloons have to enter the airspace of foreign countries. AFAIK above the height of 100 Km there is no reserved airspace.* makes me think the OP is aware of balloon technology limits.

Comment: And I don't know if that is a generalized problem wrt actual weather balloons, which seem to have limited endurance:  https://www.weather.gov/bmx/kidscorner_weatherballoons

Comment: "Until now countries ignored balloons entering their airspace because they considered them innocuous meteorological balloons." I don't understand why one thing follows from the other. Couldn't they just have decided to ignore them because it was too much effort to down them?

Comment: "Could there be accusations of violating the international law regarding the airspace?" This part might be more suitable for law. SE.

Comment: There is a lot of "what if" and "will they" in this question. Please note that this community is not a good fit for speculative questions. We generally do not make predictions for the future that might or might not become true.

Comment: I'm sure someone else has also thought about [99 Luftballons](https://youtu.be/Fpu5a0Bl8eY) :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not too clear what this Q is really asking but regarding

> Until now countries ignored balloons entering their airspace because they considered them innocuous meteorological balloons. [...] I guess that also many foreign weather balloons entered the Chinese airspace, would the Chinese begin to complain about them?

China apparently has shot down balloons before, [e.g.](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/en/news/20230207_04/) in 2019:

> The [Chinese media] outlets said the Chinese military plane downed the balloon with a missile after it entered Chinese airspace in September 2019.
>
> It was reportedly identified as a surveillance balloon from a foreign country. However, it's unclear from reports published at the time which country that was.
>
> Chinese officials at that time warned that such a balloon was used by a world power for surveillance purposes, including monitoring weather conditions and terrestrial installations.

The altitude limits for national airspace are basically fuzzy. There's no international agreement on [this](https://spacenews.com/op-ed-where-does-space-begin-the-decades-long-legal-mission-to-find-the-border-between-air-and-space/).

> no one at present can say
> with certainty – from a legal perspective – where
> the “Earth” ends and where “outer space” begins.
>
> This definitional gap is evident in the main
> repository of space law, the 1967 Treaty on Principles Governing the Activities of States in the
> Exploration and Use of Outer Space, including
> the Moon and Other Celestial Bodies, otherwise
> known as the Outer Space Treaty. This treaty,
> which has been ratified by over 100 countries
> (including the major spacefaring nations), lays
> down a series of basic rules about the
> use of “outer space,” but does not define
> “outer space.”

Some countries like Australia, Denmark and Kazakhstan have set a simple 100km vertical limit, but others like the US officially remains "agnostic" as to where the limit lies. OTOH

> U.S. Air Force awards astronaut
> wings to any pilot who has gone above 80
> kilometers, apparently on the basis that
> aircraft that fly above that altitude (such
> as the rocket-powered Bell X-15) have no
> aerodynamic control.

Others have proposed the

> Von Kármán Line – treating air-
> space as ending (and space beginning)
> at the point where it is impossible to fly
> an aircraft – an attractive approach in
> theory, but subject to changes whenever
> technology itself changes.

But this is subject to technological changes. Supposedly there's a UN working group on this, but insofar no proposal has achieved consensus.

We don't seen to know how high the balloon that China shot down in 2019 was, but the one shot down by the US in 2023 [reportedly](https://www.space.com/chinese-spy-balloon-destroyed-f-22-jet)

> was flying at an altitude of 60,000 feet to 65,000 feet (18,300 to 19,800 meters), while the F-22 was at about 58,000 feet (17,700 m)

So that's well below the discussed limits of "outer space".

There's no hard legal prohibition on shooting down satellites [either](https://voelkerrechtsblog.org/bringing-order-to-orbital-chaos/) be it from the ground or with space-based [ASAT] weapons, unless they involve nuclear warheads. There is only a requirement in the Outer Space Treaty that parties conduct "appropriate international consultations" if the foresee that the shooting may affect other countries.

---

There is indeed an ICAO exception in their ["Rules of the Air"](https://www.icao.int/Meetings/anconf12/Document%20Archive/an02_cons%5B1%5D.pdf) in appendix 4 for *light* weather balloons:

> An unmanned free balloon, other than a light balloon
> used exclusively for meteorological purposes and operated in
> the manner prescribed by the appropriate authority, shall not
> be operated across the territory of another State without
> appropriate authorization from the other State concerned.

"Light" is defined as

> unmanned free balloon which carries a payload
> of one or more packages with a combined mass of less
> than 4 kg, unless qualifying as a heavy balloon in
> accordance with c) 2), 3) or 4) below [...]

Somewhat simplifying the [rest of the] rules, any balloon with a payload weighing more than 6 kilograms qualifies as heavy, but even lesser payloads may qualify as heavy under special conditions.

We don't need really to read the rest of the regs in detail since the mass of gondola/payload of the Chinese balloon that the US shot down [was](https://www.oregonlive.com/nation/2023/02/suspected-china-spy-balloon-is-surprisingly-large-what-we-know-about-it.html) in the order of hundreds of kilograms. So it did not qualify for the ICAO exception for light weather balloons.

There's also an ICAO requirement that a "heavy unmanned free balloon shall activate the appropriate termination devices" [these are specified in some detail--essentially it must drop its payload] "prior to unauthorized entry into the airspace over another State’s territory." Even when otherwise authorised, heavy balloons are subject to various restrictions when flying below 18 000 m (60 000 ft), including a prohibition of flying below that altiture in low visibility (cloudy) conditions and must use lights at night, similar to aircraft. Medium and heavy balloons must file "intended" flight path paperwork seven days prior to launch. After launch, the operator of a heavy balloon must report the position to air traffic control (even if flying above 18 000 m) at least every 24 hours or as often "as requested by air traffic services". Below 18 000 m they need to voluntarily report the position at least every 2 hours. So, this is not exactly an unregulated business.

Answer (score 4):

There is certainly a possibility to ID balloons as innocuous. The folks who release it would alert people before they did so, indicating the expected path, altitude, purposes, size of the balloon, etc. They would monitor it and keep track of its location. And if it went out of the expected path then they would alert people who would be expected to have the balloon over head. If they did all of that then the people getting over-flown would be unlikely to be perplexed.

One pictures some such agency such as NASA or a university planning such an activity. They would first find out from local airports what the best location would be to not cause trouble for various aircraft. And they would get info about radio channels to communicate, and what info the airports would need. Possibly, if there was a military base nearby, they would coordinate with them as well.

Such a balloon release would happen within a research program of some sort. The people doing the research would have a variety of interactions with civilian authorities, giving them a track record. The various civilian authorities would then have experience with such things and know what to expect. There would be discussion about the expected payloads, what would be allowed to be carried and what would not be, and so on. As a trivial example, would a balloon be required to have a robust method of brining it down in an emergency? Not necessarily a self destruct as such, but a method of deflating the balloon with a high degree of reliability.

One contrasts that with Group X releasing a balloon without alerting anybody down wind. Then denying it had anything to do with Group X. Then claiming it did belong to Group X, but it was just a science experiment, and you better leave it alone.

The likely results will be that unidentified balloons, in the future, get shot down as soon as it is convenient and not hazardous to people on the ground. And a lot of shouting about it from various countries involved. And possibly some strained relationships between the countries involved. Probably international law won't change much because the situation will get dealt with locally.

Comment: As is noted in Fizz's answer ordinary (or, depending on whose narrative you favour, actual) weather balloons are a slightly more common event than this answer assumes, and at many sites happen (with small payloads) at least 4 times a day.

Comment: @origimbo Very common, indeed. The US alone launches hundreds of them every day. The vast majority of weather balloon flights are rather short lived, maybe an hour to three hours long. The balloon rises and rises and rises, and then eventually pops. The payload then descends on a parachute. The intent is to obtain a vertical profile of the atmosphere, typically temperature, pressure, humidity, and winds aloft. This is much cheaper than is a sounding rocket, which in turn are cheap compared to much more elaborate rockets.

Comment: @origimbo I'm sorry you read my answer as stating a particular frequency of balloon release. It's not in there, but I'm sorry you read it anyway.